# Wordpress - set custom CSS classes for first 4 posts, and wrap 2 first posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

OK, I creating homepage that have 4 latest posts, and each of them must have different class to style them using CSS.

I am using this code to display 4 latest posts:

```
<?php 
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
 'category_name' => 'artykuly',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'order'   => 'ASC',
 )); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <!---posty home--->
    <div class="home-posty" style="background: #ccc; margin: 20px;">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <div class="home-post-opis">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="home-post-tags">
            <?php the_tags(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="home-post-date">    
            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Question is how to set for lates 4 post different class like: "first-post", "second-one", "third-post", "last-one". It can't be post-id or title because every new post will have different ID and layout must be always the same. How to force adding my own classes to them? I was thinking about CSS nth-child but custom classess will be better IMHO.

I also need to wrap (using DIV) first two of them. Is it possible?

Comment: You could just count like `$i++` each iteration and then check and do `<p class="your-class-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>` <- quick and dirty

Comment: You could also use `$the_query->current_post` if you want to avoid messing the `$i` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use `add_filter` to change the classes list. and `add_action` for wrapping

```
add_filter('prefix_home_posts_classes', 'prefix_home_posts_classes', 10, 2);

function prefix_home_posts_classes( $classes, $index ) {
    $post_order = $index % 4;

    switch ( $post_order ) {
        case 0:
            $classes[] = 'last-one';
            break;
        case 3:
            $classes[] = 'third-post';
            break;
        case 2:
            $classes[] = 'second-one';
            break;
        case 1:
            $classes[] = 'first-post';
            break;
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_action('prefix_home_before_post', 'prefix_home_before_post');
add_action('prefix_home_after_post', 'prefix_home_after_post');

function prefix_home_before_post( $index ) {
    if ($index === 1) {
        echo '<div class="wrapper">';
    }
}

function prefix_home_after_post( $index ) {
    if ($index === 2) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

And your HTML template, please change to this one

```
$index = 0; ?>
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) { ?>
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) { ?>
        <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php $index++; ?>
        <?php $post_classes = apply_filters('prefix_home_posts_classes', ['home-posty'], $index); ?>
        <?php $post_classes_string = implode(' ', $post_classes); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'prefix_home_before_post', $index ); ?>
            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr($post_classes_string); ?>" style="background: #ccc; margin: 20px;">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <div class="home-post-opis">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="home-post-tags">
                    <?php the_tags(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="home-post-date">
                    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php do_action( 'prefix_home_after_post', $index ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```